# How to ensure images in a flexbox container scale proportionately?

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

To my web page I would like to add a simple CSS flexbox container, with three images inside.  Furthermore, I would like to set a width for each image (e.g. 50 px), and have the height of each image automatically scaled proportionately to that width.

The HTML/CSS I have used to do this is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<img src="http://kabultec.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/logo-nbc.svg" width="50px" />
<img src="http://kabultec.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/logo-cnn.svg" width="50px" />
<img src="http://kabultec.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/logo-abc.svg" width="50px" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
}
```

But when I do this, two images are scaled proportionately to the desired width, while one disproportionately has its height stretched to fill the flexbox container ([page here](http://kabultec.org/dev/media-and-awards/)).  Why is this seemingly inconsistent behavior occurring?  Shouldn't all three images be scaled in the same manner:  all stretched or all with proportions constrained?

- If I add `align-items: center` to my CSS, the image in-question is scaled proportionately.
- The images in-question are SVG images.
- The site in-question is a WordPress site.
- The end goal is to create a layout similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4iaA.jpg) using CSS flexbox.  For now, since I am learning flexbox for the first time, I am trying to learn basic concepts/behavior by following the MDN tutorial [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Thanks.

Comment: Bingo, that did it.  Specifically, I confirmed that only the disproportionate image lacked the `viewBox` attribute.  Then, to the image in-question I added the line `viewBox="0 0 200 95.64"`.  After, the image had its proportions constrained as expected.  Thanks--how can I mark this as the answer?  Also, for the future, can you link documentation on this?  I guess this is an aspect of all SVG images?  Or does it somehow apply to flexbox cases only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the aspect ratio of an SVG image to be maintained, ensure it has a viewBox attribute on the outer  element.

The SVG specification discusses [viewBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) and [preserveAspectRatio](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute). It states that you can only preserve the aspect ratio if you have a viewBox.

Comment: Confirmed.  I added a `viewBox` attribute to the image in-question and the scaling issue was resolved.